# How to create tables without sequelize-cli (using only models)?

Tags: sql, node.js, typescript, sqlite, sequelize.js

How to create tables without sequelize-cli? My project is managing several database files, sometimes database will be created from scratch. I need to write to that database after its creation. Writing raw queries using sqlite3 was an option, but I want to keep using Sequelize.

Example of a model I want to create a table with:

```
CarType.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        details: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
      
    },
    {
        sequelize,
        tableName: 'CarType',
        paranoid: true,
        timestamps: true
    }
);

....

Car.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        brand: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
        carType: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
        },
    },
    {
        sequelize,
        tableName: 'Car',
        paranoid: true,
        timestamps: true
    }
);

/*
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   SQL equivalent: CONSTRAINT carType_FK FOREIGN KEY (carType) REFERENCES CarType(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
    |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
CarType.hasMany(Car, {
    foreignKey: 'carType',
    onDelete: 'RESTRICT',
    onUpdate: 'RESTRICT',
})
Car.belongsTo(CarType, { foreignKey: 'carType', targetKey: 'id' });
```

How to create tables (prepare database) using the Sequelize models described?

Comment: I still don't get it why you don't want to use migrations? Can you clarify that in the post?

Comment: After a good night of sleep I think I get the solution for my problem. I cannot use the migrations-cli because the project I'm developing will be like a database manager, creating new sqlite db files based on another database (mongodb) in real time. Later today I post my solution for the problem

Comment: In this case you can build a model on the fly, register it and call `sync` to create a corresponding table in DB

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found out that we only need to connect to the database file with sequelize and then, with the connected sequelize isntance, init the models:

```
const sequelize = await new Sequelize({
        dialect: 'sqlite',
        storage: dbPath,
        logging: false,
    }); 
/// for each model, init it with this sequelize method

Model.init(
    {
        column: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(128),
            ...options
        },
    },
    {
        sequelize,
        tableName: 'Model',
        ...options
    }
);
```

For my purpose, I created some methods to initialize each model on the database, therefore I can control the creation and management of many database files